# differing asymptotic notation for linear search

Tags: algorithm

I thought I understood asymptotic notation, but after starting Thomas Cormen's Algorithms Unlocked, I'm pretty confused from one of his examples.  He first goes over "Better Linear Search" and concludes that: f(n) = Θ(n), best case ω(1), and worst case O(n)

Procedure BETTER-LINEAR-SEARCH(A,n,x)

Inputs and Output: Same as LINEAR-SEARCH.

1. For i = 1 to n:
   A. If A[i]=x, then return the value of i as the output.
2. Return NOT-FOUND as the output.

Then he goes on to discuss sentinel linear search:

￼Procedure SENTINEL-LINEAR-SEARCH(A,n,x)

Inputs and Output: Same as LINEAR-SEARCH.

1. Save A[n] into y and then put x into A[n].
2. Set i to 1.
3. While A[i] != x , do the following:
   A. Increment i.
4. Restore A[n] from y.
5. If i

   Otherwise, return NOT-FOUND as the output.

He concludes that both Better Linear Search and Sentinel Liner Search have equivalent asymptotic notation:

Θ(n) is the worst case
Θ(1) is the best case
O(n) in all cases

Didn't he just state in Better Linear Search that the best case is ω(1) and worst case is O(n)?  Why is he using Θ to describe best and worst cases now?

Comment: As i understand it, these statesments are bound to the context of cases. You could say it's O(n) or even ω(1) in the worst case, but Θ(n) carries more information (upper and lower bound). The same goes for the best case. When you want to say something about "all cases", you will never be able to use Θ, because you can't bound it asymptotically from bouth sides because "constant" and "linear" are different functions.

Comment: I thought ω is always used to represent the lower bound / best case.  While  O is always used to represent the upper bound / worst case.  In BETTER LINEAR SEARCH, we see that the best case is when the item we're searching for is the first element in the array, which means ω(1).  We also know the worst case is when the item we're searching for is the last element in the array, which gives O(n).  If the lower and upper bounds are different, how does he come to conclude that f(n) = Θ(n)